# When I rotate the screen, the screen splits like this and half is black. Flutter

Tags: flutter, rotation, screen

When I rotate the screen, the screen splits like this and half is black. Flutter

[Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il68f.jpg)

[Landscaperight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTD9h.jpg)

Comment: Please include your codes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no problem with screen rotation while on the main page of the application. But when I switch to another page and return, when I rotate the screen, it looks like the picture I uploaded.

Comment: I am experiencing this situation on both ios and android devices

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you set app width by const number

Answer (score 0):

This happens to the debug package. The release package does not

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).